# How to put meta into cube's schema when i use playground/generate-schema to generate schema automatically?

Tags: cube.js

The cubejs is great.

I can use api which is '/playground/generate-schema' to generate schema automatically.It works great.

But now I want to add meta to dimensions like this:

```
--- before ---
dimensions:{
...
    level: {
        sql: `level`,
        type: `number`
    },
...

--- after --- 
dimensions:{
...
    level: {
        sql: `level`,
        type: `number`,
        meta:{
            dict:'alarmlevel'
        }
    },
...

}
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Hi  

Cube.js already supports adding meta properties to [dimensions](https://cube.dev/docs/dimensions#parameters-meta) and [measures](https://cube.dev/docs/measures#parameters-meta).

Is there a bug you're encountering, or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.How can I add meta properties to dimensions and measures by coding? Is there a API or something helpful?

Comment: Perhaps you could try using [Dynamic Schema Generation](https://cube.dev/docs/schema/dynamic-schema-creation) using `asyncModule()` instead?.